# Typecasting in C++: why use (type) expression instead of type (expression)

Tags: c++, casting

In python, type casting is done as:
`float(a)` if the variable `a` is, say an integer and needs to be converted to float.

Now consider the following C++ code:

```
int a=5;
int b=10;
cout<< (float) a/b<<endl;
cout<<static_cast<float> (a/b)<<endl;
cout<<static_cast<float> (a)/b;
```

which gives the output:

```
0.5

0

0.5
```

In the first type cast, `a` is type casted to float explicitly, and then `b` is type casted implicitly. The final answer is of the type `float`.

In the second and third type cast, depending on the position of the `()` either `a` is first explicitly converted to float, then `b` implicitly converted and then then the final value is 0.5 *or* `a/b` is first calculated as an int, and then type casted to float, making the final value 0.

There is no ambiguity while using `static_cast<type>(expr)`

My question being:

Wouldn't this be a lot clearer if the first line was written like:

`cout<<float(a)/b<<endl;`

Eliminating any ambiguity regarding in which order the type casting will be done?

C++ has no restrictions on doing just that, and yet **it isn't common practice**. Rather, `cout<<(int)a/b<<endl;` is the prevelant form, which seems to be more ambiguous.

**Why is this the case?**

Another way to frame this question would be: what advantage does the `(type) expression` offer over `type (expression)`?

Comment: The only somewhat objective answer would be that you can't write `unsigned int(3.0)`.

Comment: Contrary to your description, there is also no ambiguity.  The expression in the second has different meaning to the other two.

Comment: `There is no ambiguity while using static_cast<type>(expr)` - my experience says otherwise, I've seen plenty of code and SO questions where the author thought that such a cast provided the compiler with context such that, e.g, `static_cast<double>(5/2)` returned 0.5 instead of 0.

Answer (score 2):

The main advantage of `(type)a` over `type(a)` is that the first works for any type and the second doesn't.    Try the following and you will elicit compiler errors;

```
  unsigned long x = unsigned long(3.0);
  unsigned long *y = unsigned long *(0);
```

Beyond that, your question is based on a completely false premise.   Contrary to your description, there is no ambiguity in the meaning of any of the expressions you describe.

```
(float) a/b;
static_cast<float> (a/b);
static_cast<float> (a)/b;
```

because the second has different meaning from the other two.   `float)a/b` and `static_cast<float>(a)/b` both convert `a` to `float` before performing the division.   `static_cast<float>(a/b)` do the division and *then* converts the result to `float`.

Your real problem is that you don't understand that division `a/b`, when `a` and `b` are of type `int`, produces a result of type `int`.

I would also suggest not holding up Python as an exemplar of how C++ should handle such things.    Python 2.x produced an integral-valued result on integral division too (albeit, with slightly different behaviour than in C++).  Python 3.x introduced the so-called "true division".   There was a lot of heated discussion in the Python community over that.

Comment: I am aware of how a was converted to float explicitly, then b implicitly and the answer calculated later(as I also mentioned in the question)

Comment: And thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 1):

> Another way to frame this question would be: what advantage does the
>   `(type) expression` offer over `type (expression)`?

Actually, they are *almost* the same...

`(type) expression` is a [C-style cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-const-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used?rq=1)

and

`type (expression)` also casts, but has limitations with respect to certain [types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast#Explanation)(`int*`, `const char*` etc); Additionally, its also a constructor call for class types.

Comment: Actually, both are casts.

Comment: @aschepler, admittedly, they are. Answer overhauled. :-)